# aligning toast messages in css

Tags: html, css

I wanna align the toast messages to the bottom left corner and when there's more than one message, I wanna move them upward with a gap of about 10px from each individual message so that all of them are readable and is in the same bottom-left position but currently when I change the position to anything else other than "fixed" it goes on top and the width doesn't rely on the padding anymore and "fixed" makes a message appear on top of another. thnx for any help!

```
.success{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 4%;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: forestgreen;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.info{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 4%;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Comment: Before I understand more deeply, can you add some code like html? Or an example of how you mean?

Comment: Try a "toast" library.

Comment: I downvoted because of lack of code. Have a fixed container, and create new elements with javascript code inside that container. Give them classes based on if they are info or toast. Don't have these child elements fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some js code with it to determine the `position` of the next toasts. I think this is what you were asking.

And as @GetSet said it will be better if you use a `toast` library. Even `Bootstrap` has its own.

```js
let margin = 10;
const showToast = (type) => {
  const toast = document.getElementById(`toast-${type}`);
  toast.style.display = 'block';
  toast.style.marginBottom = `${margin}px`;
  margin += toast.clientHeight + 5;
  hideToast(toast);
}
const hideToast = (toast) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    toast.style.display = 'none';
    margin -= toast.clientHeight + 5;
  }, 5000); // Toast disappears after 5 seconds
}

showToast('success');
showToast('info');
```

```css
.success {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 18vw;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: forestgreen;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 60vw;
}

.info {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 18vw;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 60vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="toast-success" class="success">Success</div>
<div id="toast-info" class="info">Info</div>
```

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped you! Please consider marking it as correct so it can help other people checking this question also! :)